# Update item.id when track by item.id is used in ng-repeat without reseting inline styles

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

For some reasons i use an id in my `ng-repeat` and i should update it after an ajax request (*for replacing temporary id with correct id from server*).

```
<div ng-repeat="item in modules track by item.moduleid" > some html... </div>
```

After updating **item.moduleid** in controller's scope, all of inline styles will reset. Is there any way to prevent reseting styles on DOM?

Comment: Dont see any inline styles in the code in question. Use css class instead of inline styles..

Comment: Those styles are added dynamically. e.g. drag and drop position (top, left)

Comment: Who adds them _dynamically_?

Comment: Drag and drop plugin.

Comment: Instead use `ng-style` and set scope properties on drag events?

Comment: Short answer will be : nope. ng-repeat destroy and recreates elements, so anything stateless will be lost.

Comment: aaaam. So i have a hard refactor ahead :(